# Unix command to replace strings inline based on multiple criteria

Tags: string, unix, replace, awk, sed

Is it possible to replace in each line of a text file <**string3**> to <**replaced_string3**>

only if **criteria_A** *AND* **criteria_B** is valid.

#### Input:

---

string1 string2 **criteria_A** string3 criteria_B

string4 string3 **criteria_A** string5 **criteria_C**

---

#### Required output

string1 string2 criteria_A string3 criteria_B

string4 **replaced_string3** criteria_A string5 criteria_C

Remark:
For one criteria I used: sed -i '/criteria_A/s/\string3/replaced_string3/g' text.txt

Comment: What do you mean if `criteria_A AND criteria_B is valid.` The line you have changed doesn't have criteria_B

Comment: Indeed: Should have been A and C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest with `{}`:

```
sed -i '/criteria_A/ { /criteria_B/ s/\string3/replaced_string3/g }' text.txt
```